# Why can't I use "qmake" on mac after installing it?

Tags: homebrew, qmake

I'm trying to compile a project, and I need to run "qmake" before "make".

I'm on a Mac, so I use homebrew to install dependencies.

```
brew install qt
```

It successfully installed. However, when I run qmake my Mac tells me:

```
-bash: qmake: command not found
```

I'm not sure what is wrong. Why is the command not found when brew successfully installed it?

Answer (score 5):

You can type `brew info qt` to obtain the answer of your question:

```
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because Qt 5 has CMake issues when linked.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/qt/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After adding the proposed line to your `~/.bash_profile` with

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/qt/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

and running it with:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

you will have `qmake` available to your command line but if you use it beware of interactions with `cmake`.